# Flutter, android studio. main.dart file opens every run

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I'm using Flutter with Android Studio.
Everytime I run the app, in android studio, Main.dart file shows, meaning it comes into focus over any other class I have open.
Its really annoying.
Can I stop this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand what you're trying to ask, but If I'm understanding correctly you're trying to have another class run first before `main.dart`.

Before I answer you should know that the first thing that runs when you run an app in flutter is the `main()` method (just like in java) and by default the `main()` method is located in the `main.dart` file.

So if you for some reason don't want the `main.dart` file to run first then just move the `main()` method to the class you want to run first (but thats pointless, because there's no need to do that),

But if you want another screen(page) to run first e.x. login, signup etc, then you just need to specify that in the home attribute of the `MatterialApp()` Widget.

And the other way I understood your question was that you want the last view that you were working before you closed the project or Android Studio to show up first and not the `main.dart` file if this is what you meant then this is the default settings of Android Studio so just turn the settings to default.

Comment: I meant the latter, that I want to see the last view I was working on. Thanks! Where is this able to be changed in the settings?

Comment: Well the most brutal way that I know is found in the below link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2E0oYJkL4AE